# Interactive calendar/date picker with sparsely selectable dates?

Tags: calendar, datetimepicker

So basically the problem is that I have a rather long (4000+) list of dates going back about 30 years, of dates for which a user can select data from that specific date. Its somewhat sparsely populated, sometimes there are weeks missing in there. I'm currently just using a [select2](https://select2.github.io/) widget to handle this but it seems a bit lame. Anyone have a better suggestion?

Here's what it looks like now:

[image]

Comment: What is wrong with a date picker? Or are you needing to select specific dates only over the last 30 years and not just any date?

Comment: I personally like the way [WayBack Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20160311012318/http://stackoverflow.com/) handles that much data over that big of a period.

Comment: @stradled, yeah only specific dates that have data should be selectable

Answer (score 3):

4000 dates in a dropdown is something you should avoid at all costs. There are different better ways depending on your needs and technical ability. The easier one is to simply use a filter, like this:

[image]

in the example above, the filter is *broad* (see the ALL options), so it generates a limited range of dates which can be navigated with a slider (I have added both together, but the slider should show after user filtering, of course) . You can use a *strict* filter, which won't generate any range, but specific dates, as such:

```
select parameter --> (display only years with active dates for teh parameter) --> select year --> (display only months with active days) --> select month --> (display only active days within selected month) --> select day
```

There are many other options to do this, but I think the 2 above are easy to implement and very easy to understand by users

Comment: I dig it. I'm so terrible with UI stuff...